# why sed command can work directly and can't work when I write it in script file?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, command, sh

This is my context:
I have a profile named profile

```
# file: profile

MY_PATH = "/home/deng/default"
MY_NAME = "deng"
```

my test file:

```
#!/bin/sh
#file: test.sh
DJ_PATH="/deng/jian/doc"

OUTPUT_PATH="\"${DJ_PATH}/output\""
echo "OUTPUT_PATH = ${OUTPUT_PATH}"

DOC_KEY="MY_PATH"
DOC_VALUE=${OUTPUT_PATH}
echo "DOC_VALUE = ${DOC_VALUE}"

echo "sed 's:[ \t]*${DOC_KEY}[ \t]*=.*:${DOC_KEY} = ${DOC_VALUE}:' profile"
sed 's:[ \t]*${DOC_KEY}[ \t]*=.*:${DOC_KEY} = ${DOC_VALUE}:' profile
```

in terminal I run

```
$ ./test.sh
```

and the output is

```
1  OUTPUT_PATH = "/deng/jian/doc/output"
2  DOC_VALUE = "/deng/jian/doc/output"
3  sed 's:[ \t]*MY_PATH[ \t]*=.*:MY_PATH = "/deng/jian/doc/output":' profile
4   MY_PATH = "/home/deng/default"
5   MY_NAME = "deng"
```

It looks the text in profile didn't replace by DOC_VALUE ("/deng/jian/doc/output") which I want to set.  But I ran the command in output line 3. It works:

```
sed 's:[ \t]*MY_PATH[ \t]*=.*:MY_PATH = "/deng/jian/doc/output":' profile
```

output:

```
MY_PATH = "/deng/jian/doc/output"
MY_NAME = "deng"
```

SO what happened? What's the different between the command I wrote in test.sh

```
sed 's:[ \t]*${DOC_KEY}[ \t]*=.*:${DOC_KEY} = ${DOC_VALUE}:' profile
```

and the command I put directly?

```
sed 's:[ \t]*MY_PATH[ \t]*=.*:MY_PATH = "/deng/jian/doc/output":' profile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file you use `'` which don't let bash interpret the variables.

Change to `"`

```
sed "s:[ \t]*${DOC_KEY}[ \t]*=.*:${DOC_KEY} = ${DOC_VALUE}:" profile
```

or break using multiple `'`

```
sed 's:[ \t]*'${DOC_KEY}'[ \t]*=.*:'${DOC_KEY}' = '${DOC_VALUE}':' profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

```
#!/bin/sh

S=foo
D=bar

echo 'foo' | sed 's/${S}/${D}/g'       # echoes foo
echo 'foo' | sed 's/'${S}'/'${D}'/g'   # echoes bar
```